# Mockito: how to use a parameter of a mocked function?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm using Mockito and would like to do something like:

```
Mockito.doReturn(new MyObject(capturedParameter))
    . when(mockedCreatorInstance).findByParameter(anyString())
```

So when someone calls the method `mockedCreatorInstance.findByParameter("XXXX")`, the value returned would be `new MyObject("XXXX")`.

As you can see, the mocked method signature of `mockedCreatorInstance`, would be

```
MyObject findByParameter(String parameter);
```

I tried something using `ArgumentCaptor<String>` but failed.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: "I tried something using ArgumentCaptor<String> but failed." Please show what you tried, and describe in what way it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mockito documentation recommends against using ArgumentCaptor<>s when stubbing rather than verifying.

I believe you can achieve what you want with an Answer:

```
when(mockedCreatorInstance.findByParameter(anyString()))
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<MyObject>() {
        public MyObject answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            return new MyObject((String) args[0]);
        }});
```

Comment: it is missing the closing `})`